# mysql json query acts funny with boolean values

Tags: mysql

I have simple json mysql query that looks like:

```
SELECT json_object(  
  'isCreated', true,
  'active', IF(s.status = 1, true, false),
  ...)
FROM people;
```

I dont understand why `isCreated` returns `true` as expected and `active` returns `1` when expected to return `true`

I tried also to run in the mysql shell `SELECT IF(1= 1, true, false)` and I get back `1`, I want it to be true...

Comment: Probably you want to say `IF(s.status = 1, 'true', 'false')`

Comment: @Rahul no, that will give me the string ```'true'``` which that is not what i want, i need it fto be true, as boolean, and I said the isCreated works well

Answer (score 0):

In your case **true** **false** are boolean values. MySQL stores boolean values as an integer. If **true** **false** were in string format("true","false") it would have returned true or false. Assigning in if condition always treats as true. Please Check below links once.

[Sql Docs(Numberic type overview)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

[sql tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/)